# jquery empty concatenation with qjueryui's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have to add some html form with autocomplete feature to some site. I have done it many times using jqueryui's autocomplete, but this time something goes wrong. The situation is supposed to be like that:

1. text field - Select city (only values that come from the autocomplete feature are valid)
2. text field - select street from that city (again it is autocomplete field that depends on the first one.

So for that reason i created a variable to hold the first value and pass it to the second one, but it doesn't go exactly that way.
I am posting my code with comments on it with debuging:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var city = "";
var num = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#city").autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo $url; //eg http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestCity ?>",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.item)
        {
            window.num++;
            jQuery("#city_selected").html(ui.item.value);  //this alerts correctly
            jQuery("#street").removeAttr('disabled');
            window.city = ui.item.value.toString();
            alert(window.city); // this alerts correctly
        } 
    }
}); // this executes correctly - the autocomplete works and the second field becomes enabled 
var streetUrl = "<?php echo $url; //eg http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestStreet ?>/"+window.city+"/"; /* so this has to become http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestStreet/$city/ where city is given from the first autocomplete */
jQuery("#street").autocomplete({
    source: streetUrl,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if(window.num == 0)
            return;
        if(ui.item)
        {
            window.num++;
            jQuery("#street_selected").html(ui.item.value);
        } 
    }
}); // when this executes firebug tells me the url is http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestStreet//?term=...... and here is the problem. There are two forwarding slashes that tells me the concatenation isn't ok.

});

function dump() // I created this function for debuging purposes and i attached it to button with onclick="javascript: dump(); "
{
    alert(window.city); // this displays correctly
    alert(window.num); // this displays correctly
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery UI autocomplete source property is not resolved at runtime, it is initialized with the initial value and work with it unless changed with the option setting API. when the city is selected you can change the street autocomplete source url as follows. I have not checked it but it should work.

```
jQuery("#city").autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo $url; //eg http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestCity ?>",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.item)
        {
            window.num++;
            jQuery("#city_selected").html(ui.item.value);  //this alerts correctly
            jQuery("#street").removeAttr('disabled');
            window.city = ui.item.value.toString();
            alert(window.city); // this alerts correctly
            var street = jQuery("#street");
            //street autocomplete url resolved at runtime.
            street.autocomplete('option', 'source', streetUrl + '/' + ui.item.value.toString());
        } 
    }
});

var streetUrl = "<?php echo $url; //eg http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestStreet ?>
```

Comment: I ended doing it like this: source: function(req, add){  
                $.getJSON(window.quarterUrl, req, function(data) {  
                    var suggestions = [];   
                    $.each(data, function(i, val){  
                    suggestions.push(val.value);  
                });  
                add(suggestions);  
            });  
        },  
so this way it automatically sends the ?term get param. Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var city = "";
var num = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#city").autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo $url; //eg http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestCity ?>",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.item)
        {
            window.num++;
            jQuery("#city_selected").html(ui.item.value);  //this alerts correctly
            jQuery("#street").removeAttr('disabled');
            window.city = ui.item.value.toString();
            window.streetUrl = "<?php echo $url; ?>/"+window.city+"/";
            alert(window.city); // this alerts correctly
        } 
    }
}); // this executes correctly - the autocomplete works and the second field becomes enabled 

jQuery("#street").autocomplete({
    source: function(value, process) {
      $.ajax({
         url: window.streetUrl,
         success: function(data) {
             // create array from data. and store it eg. arrData variable
             process(arrData);
         }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if(window.num == 0)
            return;
        if(ui.item)
        {
            window.num++;
            jQuery("#street_selected").html(ui.item.value);
        } 
    }
}); // when this executes firebug tells me the url is http://sitename.tld/somecontroller/suggestStreet//?term=...... and here is the problem. There are two forwarding slashes that tells me the concatenation isn't ok.

});

function dump() // I created this function for debuging purposes and i attached it to button with onclick="javascript: dump(); "
{
    alert(window.city); // this displays correctly
    alert(window.num); // this displays correctly
}
</script>
```